# send data from a thread to an activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I'm creating an app that is a sort of client- multithreaded server.

The problem that I'm facing with is the next one:

The server is multithreaded and that means that it receives the data from the clients in a thread(a separate class which is not a inner class for an activity) and I wanna send that data  to a class that extends activity!!!

Is that possible?And if yes,how??

Thank u!

UPDATE:My thread is a Worker thread it implements Runnable and the data needs to ne send to a different class that extends activity!!!

Comment: Does your Activity have access to this worker thread - or to some interface/class handling it?

Comment: My worker thread is launched from another acitvity,diferent from the one I need to send this data.....I really hope is possible:D

Comment: Most definitely it should be. So far I've been going along with so called '[GlobalState](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-implementing-global-state-share-data-between-activities-and-across-your-application/)'. While this isn't necessarily a bulletproof solution, it enables you to share your worker as a global variable between Activities. All you should do is trigger it running in your previous Activity and you can access it later on on your later Activity/ies.

Comment: Is this Global State efficient?:-S....isn't there a better way:-S???

Comment: What you can't do is send result directly to this new Activity. But having a global instance of your worker makes it possible to add your new Activity as an observer for your worker for example.

Comment: From from what I've seen, GlobalState is the easiest solution by far. Otherwise I'm afraid you have to take a look on services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can send a Message from the thread back to the Activity using a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).
This [article](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html) may be helpful.

Comment: There is otherwise...from the thread to the activity...but I assume is similar..thank u!